# From 2019 to digits

Tags: calculation-puzzle

Is it possible to obtain the digits from 0 to 9 starting from 2019 and using its digits in the same order, together with the usual operations +, *, -, /, concatenation of digits, and the less usual operators ^, !, sqrt(), int()? For example, 1 = 20-19. Unary minus is allowed too.

I manage to use only basic operations and elevation to a power for all digits except 4 and 5, but maybe somebody will do better!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $0 = 2 \cdot 0 \cdot 1 \cdot 9$
> $1 = 20 - 19$
> $2 = 2^0 + 1^9$
> $3 = 2+0+1^9$
> $4 =  \lfloor \sqrt{20} \rfloor + \lfloor 1/9 \rfloor$
> $5 = 2 + 0 \cdot 1 + \sqrt{9}$
> $6 = -(2+0+1) + 9$
> $7 = -(2+0 \cdot 1) + 9$
> $8 = -(2 \cdot 0 + 1) + 9$
> $9 = -(2 \cdot 0 \cdot 1) + 9$

Comment: Ok for the first three, but I think you're not supposed to rearrange the digits

Comment: @deepthought Fixed.

Comment: Nice! 4 may also be $2\cdot 0 + 1 + \sqrt 9$

Comment: A few more for 4 and 5:

 $\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{20\times19}}\rfloor=4$,  $\lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{20\times19}}\rceil=5$  ,
 $\lceil\sqrt{2+0+1+9}\rceil=4$ , 
 $\lfloor\sqrt{2+0+19}\rfloor=4$  ,
 $\lceil\sqrt{2+0+19}\rceil=5$

Comment: and $\lfloor\sqrt{201}\rfloor-9=5$

Comment: Fun fact: $-\lfloor -x \rfloor = \lceil x \rceil.$